# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

We're getting an error when deploying a project to one of our client's servers.  The system works fine in our local dev and staging environments.  The error is:

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

We've done the obvious checks:
-  We have the references in the web.config for System.Data.Linq, System.Core, System.Linq, etc.
-  Our project's target framework is 3.5
-  We have confirmed that the ASP.NET version in IIS on the client's server is 2.0.50727
-  We have confirmed that the server has framework 3.5 installed and contains the System.Data.Linq DLL in the Windows/assemblies folder.

Any other ideas?

Comment: After installing the service packs (per Orion below), and after a few reboots, it started working.  Still not sure what the root problem was, but its working now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same compilation error when building a project from scripts, while Visual Studio 2010 was building the same project fine. When I tried to add the System.Core reference from within VS2010 it came back with an error saying that reference is set implicitly, and wouldn't add the reference.

The solution for me was to add the following reference manually into the csproj file. Note the reference's target framework is explicitly set to 3.5 (this is on top of the project's target framework being set to 3.5):

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Adding a reference to System.Core worked for us on a SQL CLR project that got converted to a SQL Data Tools project.

Comment: @HotLicks is it referenced explicitly as above in your csproj file? Can you open your .csproj file and check?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. 
Had a project created in visual studio 2012 which had to be incorporated as part of a visual studio 2008 solution.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019609/the-type-or-namespace-name-linq-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-data), similar question

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcsharp2008prerelease/thread/960c0401-6dba-47db-8a96-a2e343f6cbe4): 'You'll get this error if you don't have "System.Core.dll" referenced (the assembly which contains the core LINQ APIs).  However, all of the default templates should include this reference when you target .NET3.5.'

Comment: From my original post: "We have the references in the web.config for System.Data.Linq, System.Core, System.Linq, etc."

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem developing a website in Visual Web Developer 2010 with .NET 4.0.

VWD **could** find the namespace "System.Linq" for **files in App_Code**, but **not** for files in **other directories**. Strange but true.

The "project" was opened using "Open Web Site" so there was no .csproj file.

Copying:

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll

to the website **bin** directory caused the namespace to be found by VWD for files in other directories.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered, but just to make it clear, as to why is it that in Visual Studio, we get Build Succeeded and face problems when it tries to build in SVN or some other repository?

Reason: It’s referenced by the IDE when it invokes the build system, but not by MSBuild itself.

But after adding the Reference as **Ashby** said above, it will surely work fine. 
This issue still occurs even during Visual Studio 2012, and as I was aware of this fact, did it and everything started working fine.

Regards,

Varun Shringarpure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but a different root cause.

I had changed the namespace declaration in the designer.cs file of the dbml.  Whenever I would add a new object via the designer, Visual Studio reverted the namespace declaration, and the build failed.

Simply changing the namespace back to what it is supposed to be fixed the issue.