# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' , etc

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I just made a Linq-to-SQL .dbml file in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm getting the following 2 errors, a total of 60 times in total, mostly the first.

1. The type or namespace name 'Linq'
   does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'
2. The type or namespace
   name 'EntitySet' could not be found

I've found various similar questions here and on other sites, all of which seem to say that some extra assembly needs to be added.

I've added every one suggested, the problem persists. Another odd thing is that VS2010 itself doesn't underline the errors in the editor screen, but it does show them in the error log.

Anyways, I've seen all the existing topics and applied their solutions, the problem persists.

Some technical details:

- I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.
- I still have Visual Studio 2008 SP1
  installed. I just installed VS2010
  when it came out and didn't remove
  the older one.
- I'm running MSSQL server 2008 R2.

And here's the assemblies listed in my web.config file:

```
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Comment: Is the target framework 3.5? (You'll see it in properties/application if these are C# projects.)

Comment: Make that in to a reply and I'll give you the solution. That was indeed it... god dammit. I just don't understand why. Doesn't .NET 4 include the stuff that's in 3.5 by default?

Comment: I was just about to "offer" to take the rep for steinar's "answer", but I don't understand the solution...  :)  So, you created a new project in VS2010, added a new dbml and saw the error?  If so, that *is* weird.  I just tested that out with 3.5 and 4.0 and all required references were added automatically.  Ah well...

Comment: Yes, that's how it happened. All my websites, solutions, projects, ... they all start with target framework 4.0
When I switched this to 3.5 for this website, all the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found [this link](http://albao.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/the-type-or-namespace-name-linq-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-data/#comment-287) which solved it for me.  The net is that the following must be added to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note that the configuration/system.web/compilation tags are already there, and the assemblies/add assembly tags need to be added.  This even though System.Data.Linq is readily found by VS when building.

The failure was in App_Code.LinqToObservations.designer.cs, code that's generated by Linq from my LinqToObservations.dbml file.

(Additional background:  I likely got into this situation because I enabled Linq after the fact using the procedure found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871073/581994).)

Comment: thnx a lot it solved the problem. However I Need to confirm that the version 4.0.0.0 is of Linq assembly or something to do with do net?

Comment: @Rusty - I don't have an environment to check on, but I believe there's a way to check the installed version of System.Data.Linq.

Comment: This worked for me too. I dont understand why it is so. I add a reference and it compiles fine but when viewing in browser it is like I have not added a reference,

Comment: Not sure if this happens to everybody! But today when I was migrating an old website from 2.0 to 4.0 I noticed targetFramework=4.0 entry was made in web.config but the assembly section did not update! I then tried one with an old web application I built in 2.0 several years ago and it got converted perfectly. No idea why, but that's what I have seen. Although Hot Lick's workaround worked for me I would definitely like to know why this happened with the website set up in local IIS but not with the web application running under .net port. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer has limitations. That syntax only works for web apps. I think you should have shown the GUI instead.

Answer (score 7):

I've been having the same problem on exactly the same config except for my Windows 7 is 64-bit. Got it solved by doing `[project name] -> References -> Add reference -> System.Data.Linq` Why do you add references by hand?

Comment: The reference is already there and I still have this problem.

Comment: this helped to use SqlMethods.DateDiffDay, thank you.

Comment: @HotLicks I am having the same issue as well, reference added and confirmed in web.config. any ideas please?

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry I did mention that I had that in my Web.Config too. Also I am using VS 2015 with MVC 5

Answer (score 7):

Important, you must set in webconfig

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try following:

Add reference to **System.Data.Linq** (Right click on References folder | Select Add Reference | Select .Net tab(Is default selected) | select **System.Data.Linq** reference | click OK.

I hope this will help you or someone else.