# Which Visual Studio project types support Shift+Alt+D to open the Data Sources window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, it appears that only maybe a third of the 20 or so C# project types support using Shift+Alt+D to open the "Data Sources" window (and none that I've found ever display the mythical "Data" menu bar option).

Is there any sort of guide as to which project types will allow you to work with data sources?

Also, is there any way to "adjust" the features of a project after it's been created?

**Update:** See my answer below for how to add the Data Sources function to an existing project.

Comment: Well, I've found an admission in the Apple docs that the "Data" menu bar isn't, and that the availability of the "Data Sources" window varies with project type, but no clues as to how one predicts in advance whether it's available.  (Unfortunately, I lost track of the page where this is admitted, so I can't link to it here.)

Comment: Unless i'm just being stupid, why were you looking at the "Apple docs" for information about visual studios?

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak - You can collect the bounty by pointing out the page in "Apple docs" that provides the above information.

Comment: My question was wanting to know why you're looking in the Apple Docs for information about visual studios. Visual studios is a windows application. It's not built for, nor does it run on, mac OSx. Specifically, you referred to "C#". In visual studios, you can indeed develop in c++ and c which are two languages that can run on Apple's mac (though you can't compile for Apple from VS). However, c# cannot even run on a Mac. So, this brings me back to my question, why is the Apple documentation even important/relevant?

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak - OK, I misspoke in my first comment above.  I meant the M$ docs.

Comment: Ahh alrighty. I was very confused.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I switch back and forth between the two, and the VS stuff, in particular, keeps me in a constant state of confusion.  For the most part there appears to be no real documentation, just tutorials.

Comment: Ahh don't worry about it. And I posted what I found as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad.aspx

To quote msdn: "You can add a data source to a project only if it supports creating and working with data sources. For example, you can't open the Data Sources window in a project for a Windows Store app."

Basically, if using a database seems logical in your application, you can probably use one.

To answer your question about the "mythical 'Data' menu bar option", here's how you access it:
[image]

You just have to select "View", then "Other Windows", and finally "Data Sources"

And to answer your final question about, "Also, is there any way to 'adjust' the features of a project after it's been created?"

Yes, yes there is. If you mean as a compiled executable, one could simply decompile the project or use an ILcode editor. If you mean as a solution in visual studios, using the solution explorer you can access "My Project" and simply double click that to get a nice little gui for adjusting your project.

**EDIT:**

For an overload of information about data in visual studios, you can visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzabh8c4.aspx

For more information about just the data source window, you can visit:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83.aspx

Comment: Well, by "adjusting", I meant, eg, access to the Data Sources window.  I finally figured out how to get there (if allowed) in the fashion you describe (or using a keyboard "chord"), but virtually all the tutorials describe a "Data" menu bar option that simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you link me to one of these tutorials? In a programming course I took about a year ago we had to use a datasource in vb.net

Comment: And while the "You can add a data source to a project only..." statement is the closest I've come to finding which projects support the option, it's kind of self-reflexive and not really helpful.

Comment: I interpret it as saying, "Add away, but please remove them if you try to release it on the Windows App Store." I have never actually heard of one instance where a datasource/data binding was not accepted.

Comment: Here's one:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tzedkwye%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Here's another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5xf878ky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And in some project types the Data Source window simply cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  There is a way to add data access to a project that lacks it, per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907587.aspx.  To quote:

To create a class from a database table

- If you are working with a Web site project, and the project does not already have an App_Code folder, in Solution Explorer, right-click the project, click Add ASP.NET Folder, and then click App_Code.
- In Solution Explorer, right-click the App_Code folder (for a Web site project) or the project (for a Web application project) and then click Add New Item.
- Under Installed templates, select Linq to SQL Classes template, type a name for the .dbml file, and then click Add.

  -- The Object Relational Designer window is displayed. *[Note that this is the window that Shift-Alt-D displays]*
- In Server Explorer, drag the database tables or other objects (such as views) that you want to use with LINQ to SQL into the Object Relational Designer window.

  -- The tables and their columns are represented as a entities in the designer window.
- Save the .dbml file.
- This creates .designer.cs or .designer.vb file that is located under the .dbml file. The file contains a class that represents the database and a class that represents the table. The parameterless constructor for the database class reads the connection string from the Web.config file.

(Note that, after performing this procedure you may get a message "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'".  The solution to this problem is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873162/581994).)