# How to fix error The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

ASP.NET MVC4 application contains Helper.chtml file in App_Code folder containing Razor helpers.
After upgrading to Visual Studio Communitity edition compile error

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\admin\e209c0e0\c74032ba\Sources_App_Code\helper.cshtml.72cecc2a.cs 16
```

Starts to occur. Generated code contains:

```
namespace ASP {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;  // Error occurs in this line
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.WebPages;
    using System.Web.WebPages.Html;

    #line 1 "C:\Web\Erp\App_Code\Helper.cshtml"
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    #line default
    #line hidden

    #line 2 "C:\Web\Erp\App_Code\Helper.cshtml"
    using System.Threading;

    #line default
    #line hidden

    #line 3 "C:\Web\Erp\App_Code\Helper.cshtml"
    using MyApp.Business;

    #line default
    #line hidden


    public class Helper : System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage {
```

Error points to `using System.Linq;` line.

How to fix this ?
Using ASP.NET4

I tried to add reference to System.Core to project but got error that it is already referenced.
web.confing contains

```
<compilation debug="true">
</compilation>
```

I changed it to

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
</compilation>
```

according  [The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070501/the-type-or-namespace-name-linq-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system) and  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c970ea3d-5238-4ec7-8859-e16b40dccd3d/the-type-or-namespace-name-linq-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-systemare-you-missing-an?forum=linqprojectgeneral

but after that compile error changes to

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'global_asax' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

which points to code

```
    protected static ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
        get {
            return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
        }
    }
```

in generated helper.cshtml.72cecc2a.cs file.

How to fix this error ?

**Update**

Relevant parts of web.config are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </httpModules>

    <compilation debug="true">
    </compilation>

    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MYApp.Business" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Since you are already using ASP.Net V4, probably there is no need to apply the resolution as suggested in the shared link. Try deleting the reference of `System` and add it again.

Comment: I deleted and re-added reference to System but problem persists.

Comment: @Yogi I updated queston and added main web.config contents. Maybe this or Views\web.config can changed to fix this

Comment: You can add the system namespace reference in pages section of your web.config I guess. ` <pages><namespaces><add namespace="System" />`

Comment: I added `<add namespace="System" />` to main web.config and Views/web.config but problem persists

Comment: @Andrus Did you get a fix to this?

Comment: no. I posted it also in forums.asp.net but havent got solution.

Comment: Any new info on this problem? this is 2021 and its still happens.

Comment: I'm still battling this problem - do you have the MSBuild package installed on this machine?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try add System.Linq namespace in your default controller.

Comment: What is default controller ? App has common base class for controllers, shoult it added there ?

Comment: it's this one which controls Your action. For e.g. by default Action Controller controls Yours  login & register actions.

Comment: also please check this post and comment section it might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22873162/5600402  it appears that some of Your references didn't updated while updating VS.

Comment: This is not a matter of a missing using file or a missing reference - I've been battling this problem for months now on my development machine. 
I ended up using a clean Windows machine, with nothing else than a VS pro 2019 installed and here the project compiles. This is not a viable solution as all other team members keep getting this error in their development machine.
The underlying problem is much deeper than a silly syntax problem.

Comment: I even get this problem creating an entirely new project, in a clean solution from the VS add new project guide. Same error error message on every view.